# In Symfony2, why is a fully authenticated user also authenticated anonymously?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm writing a custom authentication provider for using an API key currently. I have it mostly working now, but one thing is baffling me. I've tracked down the part of Symfony that created this behaviour to this:

vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/AuthenticatedVoter.php:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
            continue;
        }

        $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;

        if (self::IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY === $attribute
            && $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isFullFledged($token)) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }

        if (self::IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED === $attribute
            && ($this->authenticationTrustResolver->isRememberMe($token)
                || $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isFullFledged($token))) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }

        if (self::IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY === $attribute
            && ($this->authenticationTrustResolver->isAnonymous($token)
                || $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isRememberMe($token)
                || $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isFullFledged($token))) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Why in that last section is it saying "if you're authenticated fully, or remembered then you are also logged in anonymously"? Surely, if you're logged in anonymously then you are not fully fledged, or vice verse.

The reason I'm trying to solve this issue is because I have a firewalled part of my API that you pass a username and password to in order to create a token for authentication from then on. I want this area to only be accessible if you're not authenticating with an API key already, i.e. if a user is 'logged out' (in stateless form).

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I followed vaguely followed this guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

I copied the original Symfony voter and changed it to look like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
            continue;
        }

        $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;

        if (self::IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY === $attribute
            && $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isFullFledged($token)) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }

        if (self::IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED === $attribute
            && $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isRememberMe($token)) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }

        if (self::IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY === $attribute
            && $this->authenticationTrustResolver->isAnonymous($token)) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Then I added the service:

```
pp_security.apikey_authenticated_voter:
    class: %pp_security.apikey_authenticated_voter.class%
    arguments:
        - "@security.authentication.trust_resolver"
    public:     false
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
```

Then, in my applications `security.yml` file I added the following:

```
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
```

This meant that instead of Symfony granting access if a single voter allowed it, now it requires all voters to grant access, which then of course takes this new voter into consideration.

Now, a user is ONE of the three, and no more.

Answer (score 0):

I user this function to tell is someone is logged in:

```
public function isAuthenticated()
{
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    return $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');
}
```

so in your controller action you can use

```
if (isAuthenticated()) {
     throw $this->createNotFoundException('This page does not exist');
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm after really. I can find out if a user is authenticated in a specific way easy enough. Just the way Symfony seems to assign permissions seems odd. Being fully authenticated should mean you aren't anonymous, yet in Symfony you're both by default.